# Configure wso2is-5.6.0 with wso2am-2.5.0 to access XACML Policy : getting an error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

following this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML)

While created XACML policy in wso2is accessing from wso2AM created one POST type function and while sending request in wso2AM store getting an error

> [2019-01-14 16:19:07,008] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
>   javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect
>   at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
>           at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:53)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
>           at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
>           at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.(AMQConnection.java:485)
>           at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
>           ... 13 more
>   [2019-01-14 16:19:07,016] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
>   org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.OutputEventAdapterRuntimeException: Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.handleException(JMSConnectionFactory.java:197)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:278)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
>           at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect
>           at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
>           at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:53)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
>           ... 10 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
>           at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.(AMQConnection.java:485)
>           at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
>           ... 13 more
>   [2019-01-14 16:19:07,018] ERROR - JMSMessageSender
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:88)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [2019-01-14 16:19:07,488]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : localhost/127.0.0.1:9776

Comment: Have you updated the jndi.properties properly?

Comment: why should i update jndi.properties. I haven't find any clue to update this file. And i also don't know what should i update in jndi.properties file

Comment: @dilin993 i have update jndi.properties file comment second '/test' url line after that i am getting error. error here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186144/unable-to-access-xacml-policy-in-wso2is-5-6-0-from-wso2am-2-5-0-getting-error)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this error and was able to fix this by help of [this](https://wso2.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/APIMANAGER-5841/APIMANAGER-5841.html) page.

If you have changed the password of the super admin from `/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` you need to change it in `/repository/conf/jndi.properties` as well.

One important thing that you need to take care of is that the special characters in passsword string in `jndi.properties` need to be encrypted. For example if password is `admin?=` in `user-mgt.xml`, you need to write it as `admin%3F%3D` in `jndi.properties`